# Batch process videos

Tags: video

I have a range of videos filmed in the same environment. I'd like to change some basic parameters in all videos (contrast, brightness, etc; same values) at once.

What would be some of the ways to achieve this?

Comment: What has your research shown you so far? What have you tried & why wasn't it satisfactory?

Comment: I only know / tried darkroom app for macOS, but it doesn’t allow batch processing. I also know acorn, which has batch processing alas only for images.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be looking into `ffmpeg` - specifically for [its filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html).

For instance regarding brightness there's the `eq` filter.  This example darkens a video:

```
ffmpeg -i get_stick_bugged.mp4 -vf eq=brightness=-0.5 -c:a copy darkened.mp4
```